# Conditional logical operator using four variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logical-operators

I have a function that returns a condition using four variables.

```
(payload, variables) => {
   return payload.newMessage.lenderId === variables.lenderId && payload.newMessage.user.id === variables.authId
 }
```

I want to be able to say `C === D` is only if C and D exists.  What would be the optimal expression for this? So `A === B` is a sufficient condition if C and D doesn't exist, but if C and D exist, `A === B` and `C === D` both have to be met.

Comment: What if C exists, but D doesn't, or vice versa? Or is that not possible, and either both will exist, or both won't? What are the possible values of these variables - will they be truthy, if they exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A and B must always be equal, and one of the following must be true:

- There is no C
- There is no D
- C and D are equal

`(A === B) && (!C || !D || C === D)`

Beyond this construction, you should know what you mean by "exists" - is it enough that they not be `undefined`? Is it any truthy value? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function customCheck(a,b,c,d) {
  const abComparison = a === b;

  if (c && d) {
    return abComparison && (c === d);
  }

  return abComparison;
}
```

From your description seems something like above?

Comment: double check your `c && d` inside the `if`

Comment: @charlietfl: Ha, yes! Thanks